# FK Duplicada Entity Framework Relación One-To-Many

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

estoy intentando hacer una relación muy simple Una-A-Muchos con propiedad de navegación y listado de entidades hijas.
Si lo hago por defecto parece que todo lo hace bien, pero si intentado cambiar el comportamiento de la FK al borrar ponerlo a Null, me duplica la FK creándome una con el OnDelete SetNull y la otra por defecto

Entity Framework 2.2

Entidades

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice: BaseEntity
{
    [Display(Name = "Invoice Number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Amount")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public ICollection<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLine { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceLine: BaseEntity
{
    [Display(Name = "Invoice")]

    [ForeignKey("Invoice")]
    public int? InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
[...]
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().ToTable("Invoice");
    modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceLine>().ToTable("InvoiceLines");
}
```

Parte donde modifico el ModelBuilder para cambiar a SetNull on Delete

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().ToTable("Invoice");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().HasMany(i => i.InvoiceLine).WithOne("Invoice").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

        modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceLine>().ToTable("InvoiceLines");
        modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceLine>().HasOne(i => i.Invoice).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

He intentado poner solo una parte de la defición de la FK, ya sea desde Invoice o desde InvoiceLine (HasOne o HasMany) con el mismo resultado.
Este es la salida del Add-Migration con la FK DUPLICADA

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "InvoiceLines",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                Visible = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                InvoiceID = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                ItemName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                InvoiceID1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_InvoiceLines", x => x.ID);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_InvoiceLines_Invoice_InvoiceID",
                    column: x => x.InvoiceID,
                    principalTable: "Invoice",
                    principalColumn: "ID",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.SetNull);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_InvoiceLines_Invoice_InvoiceID1",
                    column: x => x.InvoiceID1,
                    principalTable: "Invoice",
                    principalColumn: "ID",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Según la doc de microsoft, creo que lo stoy haciendo bien, por qué me genera otra FK?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hay un parámetro para indicar la propiedad de navegación:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceLine>().HasOne(i => i.Invoice)
                                  .WithMany("InvoiceLines")
                                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```